# Updating Python 2 to python 3 in MacOS and now I cannot use python

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, updating

I was trying to update my mac from python 2 to python 3 using this tutorial and tried the section called "what we should do"

https://opensource.com/article/19/5/python-3-default-mac

and everything is going well and I got to the part where you have to remove the "aliases we used in the sections above" and first I forgot to change his username to mine so It was not broken and I could still call python on the terminal and it would give me python 2.7.2 rather than the 3.7 I had installed and set to default.

```
aaaaaaaaas-MacBook-Pro:~ $  which python
/usr/bin/python

aaaaaaaaas-MacBook-Pro:~ aaaaaaaaa$ /Users/mbbroberg/.pyenv/shims/python
-bash: /Users/mbbroberg/.pyenv/shims/python: No such file or directory

aaaaaaaaas-MacBook-Pro:~ aaaaaaaaa$ python -V
Python 2.7.16
```

Then I noticed I used his username rather than mine so I decided to change it to mine.

```
aaaaaaaaas-MacBook-Pro:~ aaaaaaaaa$ which python
/Users/adrianabeltran/.pyenv/shims/python

aaaaaaaaas-MacBook-Pro:~ aaaaaaaaa$ /Users/aaaaaaaaa/.pyenv/shims/python 
Python 3.7.3 (default, Jun  8 2020, 13:42:02) 
[Clang 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> python -V
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'python' is not defined
```

and now I cannot use python on my computer anymore. when I call for the version or try to run python from the terminal it cannot find it and my pycharm ide does not run python either. I have tried to redownload python 3 and I still can't do it and I've looked to find the path I did and I cannot find it on my finder. I don't care if we could only turn it back to python 2 but  please help me I really want to get to coding in python soon. Thank you!

Comment: It looks like it worked to me. The last line doesn't work because you're in the python interpretor, not BASH. Open a new terminal and try `/Users/aaaaaaaaa/.pyenv/shims/python -V`. You can also write the line `alias python3='/Users/aaaaaaaaa/.pyenv/shims/python'` in your `.bash_profile` if you want to be able to just type `python3` to launch python3 and `python` to launch python2

Answer (score 0):

Yo I wouldn't use pyenv that way...it's not quite how it was intended, to call the executable in the `shims` folder directly.  What I do is put `eval "$(pyenv init -)"` into my `.bash_profile` (or `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` depending on your shell of choice), and then using `pyenv`'s commands, such as `pyenv global 3.8.0` or `pyenv local 3.7.0`, that init command should automagically handle which python gets called when you invoke `python` on the command line.